# Oracle - Date - Date Issue

Tags: oracle

I am trying to calculate the difference between dates. I only need the decimal of a day so date - date is all I need.

The issue I have is, this works for some records but not others, with no real pattern. Using the below:

```
select (case when c.call_answered_date is null then c.call_ended_date - c.call_entered_queue_date else 0 end),
C.CALL_ENTERED_SYSTEM_DATE, C.CALL_ENTERED_QUEUE_DATE, C.CALL_ENDED_DATE
```

I get

```
abd_wait              call_entered_system_date        call_entered_queue_date     call_ended_date
--------              ------------------------        -----------------------     ---------------
5.78703703703704E-5   06/01/2020 12:30:00             06/01/2020 12:30:11         06/01/2020 12:30:16
0.000844907407407407  06/01/2020 12:35:38             06/01/2020 12:35:49         06/01/2020 12:37:02
```

So the second line works as expected, the first does not. But I do not know why.

I need them to all be a decimal of a day like the second line.

Please help.

Comment: The first line is in scientific notation. `5.78703703703704E-5` = `0.0000578703703703704` = `(16-11)/24/60/60`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line has the correct value and is just in scientific notation: `5.78703703703704E-5`
is the same as: `0.0000578703703703704` which is 5 seconds expressed as a fraction of a day: `(16-11)/24/60/60`. The value is still a (decimal) number it is just displayed in a slightly different format.

If you want it as a fixed formatted decimal string then use `TO_CHAR` to give the number an explicit format:

```sql
select case
       when c.call_answered_date is null
       then TO_CHAR(
              c.call_ended_date - c.call_entered_queue_date,
              '0.000000000000000000'
            )
       else '0'
       end,
       C.CALL_ENTERED_SYSTEM_DATE,
       C.CALL_ENTERED_QUEUE_DATE,
       C.CALL_ENDED_DATE
FROM   your_table c
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you! Is there any reason for the inconsistencies?

Comment: Yes, the first row is a tiny number so its displayed in scientific notation to remove the zeroes at the front so that a more precise answer can be given (the `E-5` at the end tells you how many zeroes it has been shifted by). The second row is a larger number and Oracle determined that there was less value to converting it to scientific notation.

Comment: Ah, when grouped and averaged, it still picks up the scientific notation, is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: If you want the string to be **displayed** to the user in a non-scientific notation then convert it to a string using `TO_CHAR` (as I state in the answer). If you want the **value** (for later computations) then you don't care what format Oracle uses so long as it is accurate.